# selecting a column on different order from sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table structure. I want to select distinct user_id according to office_id with lastest login_datetime.

```
tbl_id      user_id     office_id login_datetime
----------------------------------------
1           2           28          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
2           2           15          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
3           3           20          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
4           4           28          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
5           2           28          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
6           4           15          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
7           3           20          12/28/2012 5:35:50 AM
```

I tried like :

```
SELECT user_id as u_id,office_id,
(select login_datetime from tbl t2 where t2.user_id=u_id AND ROWNUM=1 ORDER BY t2.tbl_id DESC ) as LAST_LOGIN  
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user_id,office_id
```

But, its not working for me, any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another sollution is a direct `group by` with a `keep dense rank`:

```
select user_id, office_id, 
 max(login_datetime) keep (dense_rank first order by login_datetime desc) as latest_login_datetime
from tbl
group by user_id, office_id
```

or if you want unique user_id:

```
select user_id, 
 max(office_id)  keep (dense_rank first order by login_datetime desc) as lastest_office_id, 
 max(login_datetime) keep (dense_rank first order by login_datetime desc) as latest_login_datetime
from tbl
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 3):

use `Window Function`

```
SELECT  tbl_id, user_id, office_id,login_datetime
FROM    
    (
        SELECT tbl_id, user_id, office_id,login_datetime,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, "office_id"
                                    ORDER BY login_datetime DESC) rn
        FROM tableName
    ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/012e4/15)

Answer (score 0):

OK, i have changed the example to ORACLE

I will explain the query

First i am selecting a distinct user_id and office id (so if a user belongs to two offices he will returns twice)
and then the MAX login_datetime to get the latest datetime,

Then in the WHERE i am filtering the query by the office_id where it equles to all distinct offices. (basically i am returning a distinct table of office_id)

In the end i am grouping by user_id and office_id because of the MAX function

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT "user_id" ,
"office_id",
 MAX("login_datetime")
FROM TableName
WHERE "office_id" IN (SELECT DISTINCT "office_id" FROM TableName)
GROUP BY 
  "user_id",
  "office_id"
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/012e4/40)

Comment: The question is on Oracle.

Comment: I don't understand `WHERE office_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT office_id FROM @tbl)` The office_id is already in tbl.

Comment: i have change my query to ORACLE and added some explanation... Hope it will help

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. The IN clause is essentially saying `where office_id = office_id` (and a distinct is useless in a sub-query anyway). And I'm pretty sure the quoted identifiers lead to an "unknown column" error.